# My line through isnt working on a dynamically created icon

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have been working all day trying to make on line through work dynamically created icon but I can't seem to get it to work. I would appreciate any help.

js

```
    function renderTodos() {
    list.innerHTML = '';

     todos.forEach((todo, index) => {
     list.innerHTML += `
     <div class="todo" id=${index}>
     <i class= "fa  ${
     todo.checked ? 'solid fa-check' : 'regular fa-square'
     }"  data-action="check" 
    ></i>
     <p class= "text "${todo.checked ? 'linethrough' : ''}  data-action="check">${
      todo.value
     }</p>
     < input type="text" class="edit-input hidden" value=${todo.value} />
     <i class='fas fa-ellipsis-v edit-task'  data-action="edit">
    </i>
     <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can trash-btnn hidden " data-action="delete">
    </i>
    </div>

    `;
    });
    }
```

js another part

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const el = event.target;
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (el.classList.contains('fa-square')) {
    el.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.toggle('linethrough');
  }
});
```

When I try to run this it doesn't toggle

---

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const el = event.target;
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (el.classList.contains('fa-square')) { 
    el.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.toggle('linethrough');
  }
});
```

```css
.linethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="todo">
  <i class="fa regular fa-square" data-action="check"></i>
  <p class="text" data-action="check">todo value</p>
  <i class='fas fa-ellipsis-v edit-task' data-action="edit"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can trash-btnn hidden " data-action="delete"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: You are binding an event listener in an event listener? Every time you click, you are adding another event.

Comment: hey I moved my code but i still have the same problem i will update it

Comment: I tested your code and it is toggling fine. I made a runnabled snipplet in your code

Comment: hey @epascarello the line-through is working for you?

Comment: Run the code I added to your question

Comment: ok @epascarello so that works so  I guess that means I have a problem somewhere else in my code...

Answer (score 2):

With quick glance problem seems to be that you're trying to assign event.target to el and there is no event variable in that scope which leads to el being undefined.

So in the second part change:

```
const el = event.target; <- replace this
const el = ev.target; <- with this
```

Comment: thanks but i still have the same problem

Comment: Other thing that pops out in that template literal of yours is those spacings between properties and its values. Make sure you follow similar convention that is in the example provided via edit in your question. For example check where you set classes that those are `class="linethrough"` and not `class= "linethrough"`. Those spaces might just be in the code you pasted here.

Comment: ok i will try it